# Format tooltip as currency and turn on compare mode

Tags: r, tooltip, googlevis

I'm trying to solve two problems using googleVis package.

I've been scouring the internet for days and trying to answer the following:

1. How can I change the tooltip data format to be in a currency format? 
   [image: Image 1]
2. Is it possible to have a googlevis linechart be in "compare mode" and have both values from each y variable highlighted simultaneously? (like in Google spreadsheet charts) 
   [image: Image 2]

System Info:

```
RStudio Version 0.98.484
R version 3.0.1 (2013-05-16)
googleVis version 0.4.7
Mac OSX 10.9.1
```

Answer (score 3):

To answer your second question, include `focusTarget = 'category'` within your options argument.